# Change date format in SQL for ASP

Tags: sql, asp-classic

I have the following code:

```
"SELECT top 1 * FROM CensusFacility_Records WHERE Division_Program = 'Division 1' AND JMS_UpdateDateTime = '" & date & "'"
```

The date format in column JMS_UpdateDateTime is: 
8/22/2013 12:00:07 AM
How can I make sure that my "date" in the query is converted to the correct time format?

My date variable in my SQL query is a real/date time. I would like for it to match the format within the JMS_UpdateDateTime field.

Comment: Are you saying the database field is a string and your `date` variable in code is a real date/time? Or the other way around, where the database has a `DateTime` and your variable is a string?

Comment: My date variable is a real/date time. I would like for it to match the format within the JMS_UpdateDateTime field.

Comment: I'm going to assume that you have an appropriate datatype in your db, which is date/time.  Pass a datetime parameter from asp and the problem you described has been solved.  The problem I'm going to mention concerns having a datetime field equal to an exact value down to the minute.  That could cause problems.  You might be better off with having the field >= something and < something else.

Comment: I added a workaround answer. I'm not familiar with the VBScript date functions, but there should be a VBScript feature which allows you to format a date in whatever format you choose, which should be something like `M/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt` or something similar. Even so, the best answer is going to be to fix your data/database so that you've got a real date/time in your database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your database table is small enough, you can cast the value to an actual `datetime` inside your query, and pass the value in as a `datetime` parameter, so you're comparing dates instead of comparing strings.

If your table has a decent amount of records, don't do this, because it will be a performance hog.

```
SELECT top 1 *
FROM CensusFacility_Records
WHERE Division_Program = 'Division 1' 
AND cast(JMS_UpdateDateTime as datetime) = @dateParam
```

I believe SQL Server will be able to read the string that's in your database and automatically cast it properly, assuming your server settings are standard.

But in any case, use parameterized SQL instead of passing in a string like you've got.

Answer (score 1):

The format of your SQL `DateTime` is actually a bit of a red herring here - it can be displayed in any way the front end (e.g. Management Studio) chooses. The important thing here is that your `date` variable is in an unambiguous format. With this in mind I'd recommend using the ISO 8601 date/time format, e.g. `date.ToString("o")` (assuming `date` is a DateTime).